# Kingsway soft SSIS dynamics crm migrating marketing lists and connections

Tags: ssis, migration, dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

Is there a certain process to follow when migrating connnections between records and connection roles using  kingswaysoft package as it seems to create duplicate connections.

Also what is the process of migrating marketing list members for both static and dynamics marketing lists?

Answer (score 1):

In order to migrate the connection between records, you would need to work with the **connection** entity. To create a connection between two records, you would need to specify a source record and a target record in the CRM Destination component, in which case you can use the **record1id** and **record1idobjecttypecode** fields to specify the source record and **record2id** and **record2idobjecttypecode** fields to specify the target record. If you want to specify the relationship between the participants in the connection, you would need to specify the **record1roleid** and **record2roleid** fields.

In regards to the migration of marketing list and marketing list member, you would need to work with the **list** and **listmember** entity. You may need to migrate the **list** entity first and then the **listmember** and specify the **listid** in the CRM destination component. The **type** field in the **list** entity defines whether the list is static or dynamic, we do offer a [CRM Migration Starter Pack](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/blog/2016/09/16/Announcing-Migration-Starter-Pack-for-CRM-Online-and-CRM-On-Premise) which can give you some general ideas of the migration process, you can find more detail on our [KingswaySoft's website](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-365/download).

Comment: i keep getting error code -2147220969 when trying to migrate marketing lists

Comment: @KCodeR The error code -2147220969 usually indicates that the object with a specific id doesn't exist in your Target system. You can try to enable the "Redirect rows to error output" option in the Error Handling page of CRM destination component to locate the error records for troubleshooting. If you have any further questions, please feel free to reach out to us through our [official support channel](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us).

Comment: How about the duplicate connections created?

Comment: @KCodeR A connection is stored as two record in the database, when you read from CRM, you may get two record for two different directions(e.g. employer and employee). There is a field in the connection entity called ismaster, which indicates whether this record is the master record of the connection. When you do the migration, you may need to make sure you only takes the master record (ismaster is true).

Comment: Thank you for that - i did try that and seems to have worked. Could you also please explain the process of migrating marketing lists as i keep getting errors when migrating mine across , ive done the steps above. Regards

Comment: @KCodeR You're very welcome. For marketing list, it should be good if you have followed the migration strategy in our CRM Migration Starter Pack. If you keep getting errors, can you please post the error here or send the full error message through our [official support channel](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us)?